# Modelsim 10.3d simulation won't stop

Tags: modelsim

I'm using this script to run the simulation

```
#vlib work
view structure
vsim -t 1ps -voptargs=+acc -L work BiPhase_tb
do BiPhase_wave.do
run -all
```

From what I see the simulation time is 1 picosecond, but the siumlation won't stop at that and just continues running (this is my understanding from the status bar underlined in the screenshot below):

[image: Modelsim simulation won't stop where it should]

How do I make the simulation time a specified duration (e.g. 1ps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have told it to `run -all`. If there is no end condition, nothing that makes it stop like `$finish`, then it will just keep running and running and running.

If you instead call `run 10ns` it would run for 10 nanoseconds and then stop.

---

For the `vsim` command, the `-t` flag doesn't specify the *length* of the simulation, it specifies the *precision* of the simulation. In your case you are saying that you want every tick of the simulation to be 1ps.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because this is code from a video tutorial and there the simulation completes almost instantaneously and for me it runs for a while, probably there's a bug in the code after all.